# Eclipse Juno not showing Avd Manager button in Window nor a a button on the navigation tab

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I'm using Mac and Eclipse Juno . I installed all packages successfully and I  but Eclipse is not showing the AVD Manager in  window .I cant find the button for AVD manager anywhere . Why?

Answer (score 0):

Main problem could be that Eclipse not currently supported for android development. Try to switch to Android Studio http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html